# Microsoft-Cognitive Text Translation API

Tags: php, azure-cognitive-services

AZURE - The official documentation and examples for PHP is not working, help?

I am using the code at this link:
https://github.com/courtney7/HTTP-Code-Samples/blob/37a4431f75397e1ccc6ee3f62ef14b3909a2dc85/PHP/PHPAzureToken.php

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: getToken() function is not responding, it is not returning any token. Kindly let me know how can I access token.

Answer (score 0):

Always test and debug APIs using `curl` (i.e. take a `curl` first approach). Here's an example that works on my Windows 10 system. Here's the `curl` that gets a token.

```
curl -k --data "" "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:<your Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key>"
```

Example to get token and call text translate.

```
curl -k --data "" "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:<your Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key>" > Bearer.txt
set /p Bearer= < Bearer.txt
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %Bearer%" "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?Text=Hello+world.&From=en&To=es"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, kindly let me know what should I have to change in getToken(). Have a look on code:
 https://github.com/courtney7/HTTP-Code-Samples/blob/37a4431f75397e1ccc6ee3f62ef14b3909a2dc85/PHP/PHPAzureToken.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling the correct endpoint "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken"

Comment: I am calling the correct end point, that you shared, this url is same as I am using in my code but I am not able to get token.